# Get Querystring from HTTP POST?

Tags: c#, web-services, api, restful-authentication

This code seems to be getting the querystring from a HTTP Get...

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

How do I get the querystring from a HTTP POST?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["somekey"]
```

Both **GET** and **POST** have querystring in the Request. Only **POST** has the form data.

You shouldn't be doing `QueryString.ToString()`. That will evaluate ALL the keys in the NameValueCollection. You should be using the indexer to retrieve the key you want, or enumerating with the Keys property.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) for your form data.  `Request.QueryString` will always be the querystring (stuff after the question mark in the URL).

Comment: He said he wanted the querystring, not the form data.

Comment: Just because someone asks for something doesn't mean they know what they are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for all HTTP verbs.